# TDD & BDD? Which, Why and How?

Tags: tdd, bdd

TDD & BDD? Which, Why and How?

Can anyone give a good explanation to justify "Which", "Why" and "How" on both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Article on topic: [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)

Comment: Your question should be reasonably scoped and specific. I'd try doing some research on the matter and if you need some clarifications, then ask them on SO. Also read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#d) on what consititutes a good question

Comment: kibyegn, I know its not well scoped but what I am asking here is a strong evidence on both, so that I can understand it well. I will keep your suggestion in mind for next time, and wait for the outcome of your research. Thanks though.

Comment: Voting to close - since a complete answer to your broad question would need pages and wouldn't fit in the SO QnA format. Also this is slightly a subjective question... depending on the poster and the context of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDD is used more for unit testing e.g. testing a method on a class. BDD is used for testing the behaviour of a system e.g. Creating a user, or Sending out new product emails.

So for TDD you might see something like.

```
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange.
    var sut = new ClassToTest();

    // Act.
    int result = sut.SoSomething();

    // Assert.
    Assert.Equal(result, 23);
}
```

With BDD (depending on the tools you're using) you tend to see something like this:

```
Feature: Add a user
    As a system admin
    In order to give a user access to the site
    I want to create a user account

Scenario: Creating a basic user
    Given I have the user's name
    When I create a new user account
    Then that user can log onto the site
```

As you can, BDD is testing the behaviour of a system rather then single unit. Here is a very good intro to BDD by Dan North - http://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/

I would recommend using TDD when you are building your classes/code and want to testing little bits of it at a time. Use BDD when you want to test more then one of those classes in a test i.e. integration test.

EDIT:

With the how side of things, for BDD I would recommend using [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/specflownew/). This is a popular BDD tool which adds a lot of functionality to Visual Studio for creating feature files (The Feature: stuff I mentioned above) and running and debugging the tests.

Under the hood SpecFlow can use NUnit or MSTest to generate the tests. Other BDD tools include:

- [MSpec](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications)
- [NSpec](http://nspec.org/)
- [SpecsFor](http://specsfor.com/)
- [StoryQ](http://storyq.codeplex.com/)

and many others I've forgotten about right now :) I would suggest you try them out and see which one you prefer.

For TDD you have many options including:

- NUNit
- xUnit
- MSTest

A lot of the above tools can installed via NuGet in Visual Studio, which is handy.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that was nice and sweet explanation to start with, but still I will look for a big dig as I want to go in depth of Which, Why and What. Cheers.

Comment: Regarding the "What" part of your question, we need  to know what platform and programming language you intend to use e.g. Windows/Linux/Mac? .NET, Ruby on Rails, etc?

Comment: Sorry for typo Jason, it was How and not What. I was thinking something else while typing. FYI, I am using .Net over Windows platform. thanks

Comment: Right, that was very helpful, I will explore more by visiting links you mentioned. Cheers.